# Getting Null object in HashMap implementation

Tags: java, android

Iam trying t get values from a HashMap but when i call him and setText the value i always get Null, let me show the code:

```
 MyValues.class

    private List<ItemsBean> items;

    public List<ItemsBean> getItems() { return items;}

    public void setItems(List<ItemsBean> items) { this.items = items; }

   public static class ItemsBean {


    private Map<String, leakBean> Gitt;

    public Map<String, leakBean> getGitt() { return Gitt;}

    public void setGitt(Map<String, leakBean> Gitt) { this.Gitt = Gitt;}

    public static class leakBean {

    private int id;
    private String dev;

    public int getId() {return id; }

    public String getDev(){return dev;}

    public void setId(int id) { this.id = id;}

    public void setDev(String dev){this.dev = dev;}
 }
```

I´m using Gson so for get the values and use it for .setText or Toast im trying to access like this:

```
MyValues object;

txt1.setText(String.valueOf( object.getItems().get(0).getGitt().get("id")));
```

Here i get null, can someone helpme with this? i just need to access to values, also the items.size(); return 1 and must return 3

here is hte JSON:

```
{
"id": 1001,
"name": "Super1",
"user": {
    "name": "The Super 1"
},
"items": [
    {
        "987987M7812b163eryrt": {
            "id": 1,
            "dev": "seed"
        },
        "90812bn120893juuh": {
            "id": 2,
            "dev": "none"
        },
        "981273jn19203nj123rg": {
            "id": 3,
            "dev": "mine"
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: 'items' has only one object and that object has 3 more attributes, check position '[' and '{'.

Comment: Thanks i will consider it in a new implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with these POJOs:

**MyValues.java**
    public class MyValues {

```
    private int id;

    private String name;

    private User user;

    private List<HashMap<String, ItemsBean>> items;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, ItemsBean>> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<HashMap<String, ItemsBean>> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

**User.java**
    public class User {

```
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**ItemsBean.java**
    public class ItemsBean {

```
    private int id;
    private String dev;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDev() {
        return dev;
    }

    public void setDev(String dev) {
        this.dev = dev;
    }
}
```

You can no access the values like so:

```
object.getItems().get(0).get("987987M7812b163eryrt").getId();
```

Comment: Thanks thats helped me to solve the problem, i re-define the `MyValues.class` structure, by removing Gitt Object and saving the `HashMap<>` values in item object, wasn´t necesary the `List<>` because was only 1 object and many objects inside that unic exterior object (Gitt). Thanks!Thanks!